# How to construct an ellipsoid using Ansys design modeller (or any other 3D CAD software)

Tags: numerical-analysis, numerical-modelling

I am working on numerical simulation of breast model to evaluate the use of thermal imaging for breast cancer detection. To do this I need to construct an ellipsoid rotated 30 degrees around y-axis and cut from x–y plane. The outer major and minor semi-axis lengths of the ellipsoid are set to 0.08 m and 0.05 m, respectively. I am working on Fluent for the numerical simulation and using Design Modeller to generate the model. I need help on how to create an ellipsoid using any 3D CAD software (after which it can be imported into design modeller)

Comment: You can generate an ellipsoid in several CAD software. For example, [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Download).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw an ellipsoid in ANSYS DM by following the below steps:

1. Select a plane and draw an ellipse. I selected the XYPlane.;
2. Using 'trim' (available in 'Sketching'>'Modify') remove half of the ellipse, as shown in the figure below. Note that 'trim' tool is shown on the left side of the figure.
   [image]
3. Thereafter, change the plane. In my case, my ellipse was drawn on the YXplane, and I created a new plane on the XZplane. Draw a circle (figure below).
   [image]
4. Finally, in the Modelling mode, select 'Sweep'. In 'Sweep', specify your half of the ellipse as 'Profile' and your circle as 'Path'. Done!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @StudentUC, I was able to create an ellipsoid in ANSYS DM by following your steps.